# Load a remote XML into a web page and access its content via JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, xml, api, dynamic-loading

I'd like to know if it's possible to load a remote XML file through the `<script>` tag, and access the content using JavaScript.

As the XML is a result of an external website (I'm using TheTVDb API), I can't load it using AJAX.

I'm looking for something like the following, if it's possible (JQuery-like syntax):

```
<script id="xmlload" type="text/xml" src="...">
<script type="text/javascript">
  var xmlcontent = $('#xmlload').content();
  // parse xmlcontent
</script>
```

Comment: what error are you getting? is the xml not ready? if so, maybe try doing it on `document.ready`

Comment: yes in jquery it is possible to fetch the xml, json content

Comment: No, the XML is hosted on a remote server.

Comment: Please use upvote to thank and do not thank in question.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that this is possible - you *will* need to use XmlHttpRequest (AJAX) to use a HTTP-based API. However, it might still be possible to actually do cross-site requests if the TheTVDb server allows this - see [HTTP access control](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/http_access_control) on MDN, which describes the relevant W3C specification ([Cross-Origin Resource Sharing](/http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/)).

So if you haven't done so yet, I'd recommend you just try if making an AJAX request works. Otherwise, it might be a good idea to ask the TheTVDb folks if they are so kind to implement the mentioned spec.

Comment: The cross-site request is not a problem, as I'm building a Chrome packaged application, which allows to make cross-site requests.

Comment: I don't understand the problem, then. If you can make cross-site requests, why shouldn't you be able to do an XmlHttpRequest to any server? Have you tried?